# How to "copy" linux distro packages into your own linux

Tags: linux

I'm in the middle of building my own mainline linux kernel for aarch64 and deploying it, and I would like to add software to it, including a desktop environment and a package manager like apt.

The idea I have is to take another distro like ubuntu, debian or gnome, take a list of all the software in those distros, cross compile it and use it.

How could I do this? I know there's system specific patches for different software, but I'm not interested in those.

Comment: User applications are not  and cannot be part of the kernel. Do you want to build a kernel or build a complete distribution?

Comment: @mashuptwice I have a kernel and I'd like to build applications to use with it.

Comment: I suggest you begin with [linuxfromscratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org).